# paypal express checkout ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, paypal

I have a JQuery client that I want to be able to do a credit card transaction at PayPal using Express Checkout.  The client presents a form to the user in Jquery which starts the transaction.  Via AJAX, the client initiates the purchase to the server.  I execute a SetExpressCheckout to PayPal sandbox.  I get the response token, create a url with token and send back to the client.

I want the interaction with PayPal to occur on the client but, In order for that to happen the client has to open a window to the url for the user to interact with PayPal in.  At the end of that interaction, the PayPal site redirects back to our server.

How can I get the PayPal API to work in an AJAX flow?  How can the client get control back from the window it had to create to let the user interact with PayPal? Any ideas on how to handle PayPal flow in an AJAX application?

Comment: This is all very heavily documented on PayPal's dev site and on a zillion other sites. What have you tried?

Comment: This document looks like an HTML flow only.  Is there an AJAX document somewhere?

Comment: Sorry this document https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Express Checkout Digital Goods documentation](https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/pp_expresscheckout_integrationguide_dg.pdf) will cover getting everything to work in a lightbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem was with my perspective on the redirect from paypal.  We open a window in the script to take the user to PayPal.  The script loses control.  For some reason, I kept thinking that the client was not going to be able to get control back .  On the redirect from PayPal to the server we reload the client scripts and we are back in the driver's seat.